# excel, copy cell to worksheet on next available row within a do while loop

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, do-while

I have a list that is generated when I select a beer from a drop down list. The list is not static as the list will change depending on the beer I select.  The list ranges from 1 to 14 items, and starts on column I2 and can end on J15.
[Recipe worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJBm3.png)
Column I contains the Worksheets name and Column J contains the cell data to be added to the next available row in Column A

I would like some help creating a VBA script that will loop through I2:J15 and stop when it reaches a blank cell. While copying the data from column J to the worksheet from column I to column A next available row.

I am not a VBA programmer and an OK knowledge within excel.  So frankly I've not tried anything as of yet.  I've been looking for the last 3 day but I've not been able to find anything remotely to what I'm trying to accomplish.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub CopyValuesToSheets()
    Dim recipesSheet As Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, nextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheetName As String
    
    ' Set the recipes sheet
    Set recipesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recipes")
    
    ' Find the last row in column I
    lastRow = recipesSheet.Cells(recipesSheet.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through the range I2 to last row in the recipes sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Get the sheet name from column I
        sheetName = recipesSheet.Cells(i, "I").Value
        
        ' Set the destination sheet
        Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
            
        ' Find the next available row in column A of the destination sheet
        nextRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
        ' Copy the value from column J in the recipes sheet to column A in the destination sheet
        destSheet.Cells(nextRow, "A").Value = recipesSheet.Cells(i, "J").Value
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Frist of all THANKS! With your guidance and help.  
I’ve tested the code and it work… well mostly.  It errors out.  I found where the error resides but have not been able to resolve the problem.  The variable lastRow is showing the incorrect number.  No matter what recipe I select the number remains a constant of 12.  This number coincides with the last cell in column I with a formula.  I am using a formula to display the grains of the recipe.
Any idea of how to display just the text in the rows?
Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffParten is your data same as your posted recipe worksheet screenshot it does not matter if the cell value of column I is a formula, the code will get the last row with data in column I, then from row 2 to the last row, each cell value in column I will be taken as a sheet name then copy the value of column J and assign to the next available row in column A of the sheet in column I, the code assumes column I has contiguous values and no blank in between cells